# what is the cost of Collection.retainAll(Collection)

Tags: java, big-o, linkedhashset

I wanted to find the common elements between two `LinkedHashSet<String>`, Primarily I wrote my own function but the cost was o(n^2). Then I found a better solution of `retainAll()` java built in function. 
I was wondering what is the cost of this function. O(n) or o(n^2)?

Comment: It uses the implementation from [`AbstractCollection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#404). Looks like it's linear, since it uses constant-time `contains` and `remove`.

Comment: @AndyTurner: thank you

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the implementation in `AbstractCollection`, it iterates over all the elements of the collection being called on (i.e. `n`), and for each element checks if the other collection contains it (an O(1) operation in the case of a `LinkedHashSet`).

In conclusion - this is an O(n) operation, where `n` is the size of the collection you call the method on.

Answer (score 1):

It will be at least O(N) for LinkedHashSet. For other `Collection`s like the tree sets, it will be O(NlogN), and for the rest, you are back to O(N^2).

**Note** that these measures depend on the collection you pass to the `retainAll` method. So passing a `HashSet` will be O(N), `TreeSet` will be O(NlogN), and anything else will be worse than O(NlogN)